# How to Type a function that receives a function as a parameter with spread arguments?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly type the parameter `applySnapshotFn` which is a function that will always take the arguments `snapshot` and spread `...args`.

```
const applyCssSnapshotFn = (snapshot, cssFileName) => {};
const applyJsSnapshotFn = (snapshot, jsFileName, currentVersion) => {};

const upgradeSnapshot = (
  snapshots: SnapshotType,
  applySnapshotFn: () => void, // How do I properly type this to accept ({snapshot, ...args})?
  args: Record<string, string | boolean>
) => {
  snapshots.map(({ snapshot }) => {
    if (snapshot) {
      applySnapshotFn({ snapshot, ...args });
    }
  });
};

// Calling the function
upgradeSnapshot(snapshots, applyCssSnapshotFn, {
  cssFileName,
});

upgradeSnapshot(snapshots, applyJsSnapshotFn, {
  jsFileName,
  currentVersion,
});
```

[TypeScript playground link for better example](https://tsplay.dev/m35xLw)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mAjJ1W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz That's a good idea, added. Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you want at runtime, does it?  Like, it never passes more than one argument to `applySnapshotFn()` ([observe](https://tsplay.dev/wX7O8W)).  It kind of looks like you're confusing object spread with array spread/rest arguments.  Could you resolve that confusion and come up with something that actually works at runtime, and then someone can maybe advise you on what typings to use?

Comment: @jcalz Ive proposed an updated solution applying object spread all way instead of mixing, maybe I should have waited the edit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code on the playground to propose you a solution

```js
type Snapshot = Record<string, string>;

type SnapshotType = {
    version: string;
    snapshot: Snapshot[];
}

interface UpgradeCssSnapshotArgs {
    cssFileName: string;
};

interface UpgradeJsSnapshotArgs {
    jsFileName: string; 
    currentVersion: string;
};

type SnapshoFnType<T extends UpgradeCssSnapshotArgs | UpgradeJsSnapshotArgs> = (params: { snapshot: Snapshot[]; } & T) => void; 

const snapshots: SnapshotType[] = [{
    version: '0.2',
    snapshot: [
        {
            description: 'Description of action',
            action: 'actions to perform'
        }
    ]
}];

const applyCssSnapshotFn = (params: { snapshot: Snapshot[] } & UpgradeCssSnapshotArgs) => { 
    console.log(params);
};
const applyJsSnapshotFn = (params: { snapshot: Snapshot[] } & UpgradeJsSnapshotArgs) => { 
    console.log(params);
};

const upgradeSnapshot = <T extends UpgradeCssSnapshotArgs | UpgradeJsSnapshotArgs, >(
    snapshots: SnapshotType[],
    applySnapshotFn: SnapshoFnType<T>,
    args: T
) => {
    snapshots.map(({ snapshot }) => {
        if (snapshot) {
            const params = { snapshot, ...args };
            applySnapshotFn(params);
        }
    });
};

// Calling the function
upgradeSnapshot(snapshots, applyCssSnapshotFn, {
    cssFileName: 'Theme.css'
});

upgradeSnapshot(snapshots, applyJsSnapshotFn, {
    jsFileName: 'Home.js',
    currentVersion: '0.1',
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAygdgQzAZwBYHthQLxQEoQDG6ATgCYA8ywJAlnAOYA0U1djAfANwCwAUP1CRYiFBmAAVcNFwBvfgEgAbhBLJa6OAC5WNes0XJRaTDvhITwANoBdfgF9+-esFUAzBIWgBVMAxIIZBAAwsjI5mKYAIIkDMhQ8nwKhGEAYrQANhAAcggAthA6bPq8fPalznCuJB5eUL7+gRAAUuHG4jFxCYoAVsjpWbkFRXqMXFCKhACuJCQQVQBqquqaI+wMpeVOfELQESapcFKQFBJQEAAernBk8Q0BQaFtFh2x8QA+9X4PLc+RwJ1kBwcFAABRgBABPLIHSyVjtUwiF6YWzjexQABkUAkAEocMClOhaGRxttiHBqPDkcAYUj-scILYQVZEsplhptFAAOQABgAdAAmLlMQwI4A6KyKBSshQKILIQh0MDADk6LkAEQgCqVKs0UHQbignl1cGFUoUxtV3MtmniwHQUEgNVIeS5UscSTsZS9-HJlKQYAyICe+3EhxB4Mh+VpcKM1LMYqZ6Kx9yaIbFgLx2GBcMmtvQWT5GXQDEjUOQOM2pT9WADQdaocw4dwZejsKp-wT1KTmK+jSCDYzbyzOYmST9BYgRZLrehlYcFT4NagU2+TUbWFwp3OV3mtz7P3T1MBUE+qYHf0sgJYHFBouptI3DNsIqSdZAG8OXcihwZpw4r4Wm8OgSPwI7dEkcb-MgfJ5EgoKgrGYpQPY4EyrQhqglBlh4jKyS2lgELliCSHUiwfIUZCXRbEksrvp+cCzhWpSyh6CioVW2wAPRcVAwQIBkGT6FAwCoNAbhTHAhAmvwq79hAG5YWKyAsO+R7-IcLCsik-SZDk+SFNyEhiQUfI6W6ZTzgIfByT8inYeIKlGmAgYgIO1KaRBCh9AM+nDNyAAS6CmX0ZrjjMcyLOyqzcvyACMYUcUAA)

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful and fixed the issue I was having. I definitely need to learn about the use of generics.